# SPI Read returns only 0 in slave when I hook up SS to INT

Tags: pic, spi

I am coding a SPI slave using a PIC16F877A in CCS C and need to be aware when the SS line (pin 7) goes from high (idle) to low (active) as information from the master is framed as a stream of bytes with the leading byte (first byte after SS goes active) telling me what the remaining bytes are for.

I have shorted SS (from master) to INT(pin 33) and written this:

```
#include <16F877A.h>
#device adc=16

#device *=16 

#FUSES NOWDT                    //No Watch Dog Timer
#FUSES HS                       //High speed Osc (> 4mhz for PCM/PCH) (>10mhz for PCD)
#FUSES NOBROWNOUT               //No brownout reset
#FUSES NOLVP                    //No low voltage prgming, B3(PIC16) or B5(PIC18) used for I/O

#use delay(clock=20000000)
#use rs232(baud=57600,parity=N,xmit=PIN_C6,rcv=PIN_C7, ERRORS)

// TODO: add a 100ohm resistor between the SS pin and the chip select output of the master microcontroller                                                     // Clock base   Sample on 
#define SPI_MODE_3  (SPI_H_TO_L | SPI_XMIT_L_TO_H)   //    high      trailing edge 

volatile int1 slave_cs_enabled = false; //has the slave STB been enabled?

//#PRIORITY EXT, SSP
#PRIORITY INT_EXT, INT_SSP

#INT_EXT
void slave_cs_isr() 
{ 
   slave_cs_enabled = true; 
} 

//#INT_SSP

void main()
{
   unsigned int8 data = 0;

   enable_interrupts(INT_EXT);
   ext_int_edge( H_TO_L );
   clear_interrupt(INT_EXT); //if you read the data sheet, you will 
   enable_interrupts(GLOBAL); 
   //Now the code will call the interrupt in the rising edge. 

   setup_spi(SPI_SLAVE | SPI_MODE_3);

   while(1) {
      if(slave_cs_enabled)
      {
         slave_cs_enabled = false;
         printf("STB\n\r");
      }

      if(spi_data_is_in())
      {
         data = spi_read();
         printf("%X\n\r", data);
      }
   }
}
```

All I get after STB are "00". Literally zeros.

This behavior remains unchanged even if I physically disconnect pin 33 from pin 7, pointing to an issue in my code.

When I take out the STB logic (including disabling the interrupt code), then I get stream of bytes but that is not useful to me as I now don't know where a stream starts and ends.

Help!

Comment: Even if it's an edge triggered interrupt, you should clear the flag in the handler.

Comment: Please edit your original post and let us see the code for spi_data_is_in()  Is that a function written by you, or is it supplied by the compiler itself ?

Comment: @User.1:  spi_data_is_in() is a library functions but it's literally reading SSPBUF

Comment: My smarts are on the PIC24, so throw my ideas away if they don't fit here; but where are you initializing the SPI module ? On the PIC24 I had to do peripheral pin select. I don't see that here. I will assume that the library functions are checking the SPIxBUF and SPIxSTAT registers properly. Endless nulls and the like are characteristic behaviors of a device that was not initialized properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the settings of the TRISB register. Read section 4.2 of this document (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39582C.pdf). It explains how the TRIS (tristate) registers control the input/output behavior of the PIC16F family. If TRISB[0] is set to 0 then the RB0/INT pin will be outputting low and overriding the interrupt mechanism.

I've lost many hours to that little register in the past.